# How do I shrink the default Spark DataGrid row height and keep the text vertically in view

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, flex-spark

In the Spark DataGrid the default row height is about 22 px. I would like to set the default row height to 18 pixels and I can do this easily enough with the rowHeight property but what happens is when the rowHeight is set to anything less than 22 px the bottom area of the text in each row is cut off.

It seems that the default grid itemrenderer or grid label has a min height set to it. Since I have multiple columns and want to have shorter rows but not have the bottom of the text cut off in each row how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement a custom itemRenderer.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping to find a way to do it without creating itemrenderers but in the end that was the only way

Answer (score 1):

In the end I had to create grid column item renderers. Example below,

```
<s:GridColumn dataField="@name" 
              minWidth="50"
              editable="false" 
              resizable="true"
              headerText="PROPERTY">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component className="defaultItemRenderer">
            <s:GridItemRenderer minHeight="14">
                <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
                         verticalCenter="1" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
                         fontSize="12"
                         paddingTop="3"
                         paddingBottom="3"
                         paddingLeft="3"
                         paddingRight="3"
                         textAlign="start"
                         verticalAlign="middle"
                         width="100%" 
                         maxDisplayedLines="1"
                         showTruncationTip="true"/>
            </s:GridItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```